# Sampling from arbitrary distribution in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, r, statistics

I'm trying to draw n random numbers from a non uniform arbitrary probability distribution. My initial problem was that I didn't know how to do this statistically. Now I have found a beautiful function in R that accomplishes just that. Let's say we want to generate a number `x` between 1 and 100 and we have the probability of each of them in a vector `probabilities`. Then in R we can have:

```
customDist = function(n) { 
sample(x = c(1:100), n, replace = T, prob = probabilities) 
}
customDist(1)
```

Now my question is how can I reproduce such a thing in PHP or even in Javascript? Is there a function?
P.S. The R function `sample()` is written in C.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can sample a distribution by using the npm library; https://www.npmjs.com/package/probability-distributions. The website reports that it uses the same function names as R, so this could be particularly useful to you.